# Free c# QR-Code generator

Tags: c#, qr-code

I'm looking for a free to use c# library/code to create barcodes. Secifically I need to be able to create QR-Code type barcodes. I'm looking for free to use (Open Source or just Free, etc.) not pay to use.

Comment: Take a look at this one [http://qrcodenet.codeplex.com/](http://qrcodenet.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Here is QR code generator application,you can go through the details here http://blogs.gcpowertools.co.in/2011/09/how-to-create-qrcode-barcode-using.html

Answer (score 59):

Take a look QRCoder - [pure C# open source QR code generator](https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder). 
Can be used in three lines of code

```
QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
QRCodeGenerator.QRCode qrCode = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(textBoxQRCode.Text, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
pictureBoxQRCode.BackgroundImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
```

Comment: Note that this project uses C# 6. The significance is that the licensing of free Visual Studio environments (that support C# 6) prohibit commercial use except under very few and limited circumstances. If you've purchased a VS license you will require 2015 or later to get the C# 6 ability.

Comment: The commercial use part could be bypassed by using raw msbuild to compile the project before commercial release. On the other hand - if you develop commercial software, then you could also buy a commercial version of VS.

Comment: QRCoder is really nice - it's simple, really is a few lines of code.  VS 2015 is not required ? - it works just fine in VS 2010/NuGet.

Comment: @DAG A non-enterprise client is a fairly generous circumstance, don't you think?

Comment: @MatthewM. the source code is chock full of interpolated strings... how did you get that C# 6 feature to compile in VS 2010?  For example see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31514767/string-interpolation-doesnt-work-with-net-framework-4-6

Comment: @DAG I just added it with NuGet to my VS 2010 project.  I do have .NET 4.6.x on my machine as well ; perhaps that is what enables it to work?  I did no digging - it just worked.

Comment: Sometime I get error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+. with this library. Can I solve this?

Comment: @HongNguyen try to copy your image. It is probably related to your code, not this library.

Comment: I am using VS2013 targeting Framework 4.5. Can't I use a ZKWeb version compatible with F4.5 along with QRCoder?

Comment: It works in VS2013 if you load it using NuGet because you end up getting the BIN file. You cant  change the code. But it works so why do you want to change the code? You can get the pay load generators here  https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder/wiki/Advanced-usage---Payload-generators

Comment: QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
     QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(textBoxQRCode.Text, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
     QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
     pictureBoxQRCode.BackgroundImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
The usage was updated, referenced by the same git repo

Answer (score 48):

[ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) is an open source project that can detect and parse a number of different barcodes. It can also generate QR-codes. (Only QR-codes, though).

There are a number of variants for different languages: ActionScript, Android (java), C++, C#, IPhone (Obj C), Java ME, Java SE, JRuby, JSP. Support for generating QR-codes comes with some of those: ActionScript, Android, C# and the Java variants.

Comment: @[Markus Jarderot] I'm not able to get a working download for ZXing. I downloaded the CodePlex one. The .chm documentation doesn't work - the topics load, but clicking "Display" doesn't display the content. And I can't get the solution to compile. All the projects in the solution give a long list of errors, and I can't figure out the purpose of any of the projects without working documentation, so I can't isolate and get a barebones example working.

Comment: @Zesty I'm assuming you mean [ZXing.Net](https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/). I'm also assuming the errors are signing errors. See [the documentation page](https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/documentation) for pre-requisites and steps to build. -- To view .chm files, you need to unblock them in the file properties. See [KB902225](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/902225)

Answer (score 17):

**Generate QR Code Image in ASP.NET Using Google Chart API**

Google Chart API returns an image in response to a URL GET or POST request.
All the data required to create the graphic is included in the URL, including the image type and size.

```
var url = string.Format("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs={1}x{2}&chl={0}", txtCode.Text, txtWidth.Text, txtHeight.Text);
                WebResponse response = default(WebResponse);
                Stream remoteStream = default(Stream);
                StreamReader readStream = default(StreamReader);
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
                response = request.GetResponse();
                remoteStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                readStream = new StreamReader(remoteStream);
                System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(remoteStream);
                img.Save("D:/QRCode/" + txtCode.Text + ".png");
                response.Close();
                remoteStream.Close();
                readStream.Close();
                txtCode.Text = string.Empty;
                txtWidth.Text = string.Empty;
                txtHeight.Text = string.Empty;
                lblMsg.Text = "The QR Code generated successfully";
```

[**Click here for complete source code to download**](http://www.codescratcher.com/asp-net/generate-qr-code-image-in-asp-net-using-google-chart-api/)

Demo of application for free QR Code generator using C#

[image]

Comment: Note that this API is deprecated since 2015

Comment: It still works (as of 2016-10-21).  You can even do a get. Try the following URL in your browser and you'll see a QR Code gen'd. 
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=250x250&chl=this%20is%20seriously%20cool

Comment: Can I both encode and decode with your code ?

Comment: var url = string.Format("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs={1}x{2}&chl={0}", txtCode.Text, txtWidth.Text, txtHeight.Text);

Answer (score 5):

You can look at [Open Source QR Code Library](http://qrcode.sourceforge.jp/) or [messagingtoolkit-qrcode](http://platform.twit88.com/projects/show/mt-qrcode).  I have not used either of them so I can not speak of their ease to use.