# How to find the API's to generate the barcode in C#

Tags: c#

I am Doing a project on Barcode using c#. I am facing difficulty in finding the related libraries that is needed to generate the barcode. I found some barcode classes and methods in Microsoft.policy.RecordsManagement.Policy namespace under Microsoft.policy.dll.
But this library is not preferable as we need share point to use it.

Other than this I am finding some third party barcode generators.Is there any free libraries to generate the barcode other than Free 3 of 9.?I can generate a barcode using free 3 0f 9. can anyone please help me out in improvising on my info?

Comment: Is this a flat or QR code? if the latter, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020136/free-c-sharp-qr-code-generator

Comment: I would like to use code 39 or code 128 Symbologies.basically linear barcodes.I'm looking for a free to use c# library/code to create barcodes.(open source or free)?

Answer (score 2):

[jquery-barcode](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-barcode/)

Its a javascript library to generate bar codes.

or

[LimiLabs](http://www.limilabs.com/barcode/download)

or try this site...

[www.onbarcode.com](http://www.onbarcode.com/products/net_barcode_asp_net/#down)

Comment: but I will have to purchase the barcode generator from them and then add the reference to my project.aren't there any other libraries which are free to use?

Comment: No, have you checked the sites? i guess you don't have to purchase it.

Comment: ya I have checked its only evaluation version that is free and its only valid for 30days.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on [this](http://qrcode.sourceforge.jp/) which develops and distributes QR Code decode/encode library under GPL v2.

Comment: Thank u. but I am trying to develop it in windows 7.