# String interpolation doesn't work with .NET Framework 4.6

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, string-interpolation

I just installed the .NET Framework 4.6 on my machine and then created a ConsoleApplication targeting .NET Framework 4.6 with Visual Studio 2013.

I wrote the following in the `Main` method:

```
  string test = "Hello";
  string format = $"{test} world!";
```

But this does not compile. Doing the same in Visual Studio 2015 works.
Why?

Comment: You need VS2015, which rather fortunately for you is due to  be released today!

Comment: @DavidArno You can use C#6 w/ VS2013, you just need a NuGet package. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31514767/string-interpolation-doesnt-work-with-net-framework-4-6/33179311#33179311).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

String interpolation is a C# 6.0 feature, not one of .NET Framework 4.6. VS 2013 doesn't support C# 6 but VS 2015 does.

Answer (score 29):

String interpolation is indeed a C# 6.0 feature, but C# 6 isn't limited to VS2015.

You can compile applications that leverage C# 6.0 language features in VS2013 by targeting the Roslyn compiler platform via the `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/).

My experience has been that, after this package is installed, error messages during compilation can be a little misleading. If you have compile errors that are not C# 6 related, you will be shown those error messages plus error messages regarding invalid syntax relating to any C# 6 features you've used despite the fact that you're now targeting a compiler that supports them.

For instance...

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
        var example = $"{ViewBag.Title}";
        ImASyntaxErrorWhatAmIWheresMySemicolonLOL
        return View();
    }
}
```

will result in 4 error messages during compilation:

> Error 1   Unexpected character '$'
>
> Error 2   Invalid expression term ''
>
> Error 3   ; expected
>
> Error 4   ; expected

The first 3 errors here relate to the line that uses string interpolation, only the last `; expected` error is a problem. Remove the offending line right before we return the `View` and the string interpolation compile errors disappear and all is well.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32010632/772086) for more information regarding the NuGet package for Rosyln in VS2013.